# Medium-term temporary tables - creating tables on the fly to last 15-30 days?

Tags: mysql, database, temp-tables, database-administration

### Context

I'm currently developing a tool for managing orders and communicating between technicians and services. The industrial context is broadcast and TV. Multiple clients expecting media files each made to their own specs imply widely varying workflows even within the restricted scope of a single client's orders.

One client can ask one day for a single SD file and the next for a full-blown HD package containing up to fourteen files... In a MySQL db I am trying to store accurate information about all the small tasks composing the workflow, in multiple forms:

- DATETIME values every time a task is accomplished, for accurate tracking
- paths to the newly created files in the company's file system in VARCHARs
- archiving background info in TEXT values (info such as user comments, e.g. when an incident happens and prevents moving forward, they can comment about it in this feed)

Multiply that by 30 different file types and this is way too much for a single table. So I thought I'd break it up by client: one table per client so that any order only ever requires the use of that one table that doesn't manipulate more than 15 fields. Still, this a pretty rigid solution when a client has 9 different transcoding specs and that a particular order only requires one. I figure I'd need to add flags fields for each transcoding field to indicate which ones are required for that particular order.

### Concept

I then had this crazy idea that maybe I could create a temporary table to last while the order is running (that can range from about 1 day to 1 month). We rarely have more than 25 orders running simultaneously so it wouldn't get too crowded.

The idea is to make a table tailored for each order, eliminating the need for flags and unnecessary forever empty fields. Once the order is complete the table would get flushed, JSON-encoded, into a TEXT or BLOB so it can be restored later if changes need made.

Do you have experience with DBMS's (MySQL in particular) struggling from such practices if it has ever existed? Does this sound like a viable option? I am happy to try (which I already started) and I am seeking advice so as to keep going or stop right here.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Well, of course that is possible to do. However, you can not use the MySQL temporary tables for such long-term storage, you will have to use "normal" tables, and have some clean-up routine...

However, I do not see why that amount of data would be too much for a single table. If your queries start to run slow due to much data, then you should add some indexes to your database. I also think there is another con: It will be much harder to build reports later on, when you have 25 tables with the same kind of data, you will have to run 25 queries and merge the data.

I do not see the point, really. The same kinds of data should be in the same table.

Comment: Thanks @Alfred, that's something I needed to be reminded of, that tables provide a structure for kinds of data. Because I keep reading people saying "if you have more than X fields in your table then you're doing something wrong" I was trying to go around that and break it down. As far as querying goes I can't imagine it being too much of a hassle if I keep track of the tables names in my Order table... Still your last point will make me reconsider the options I have. Cheers.